# Caching dynamic pages in .net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-caching

I have some dynamic asp.net pages. They have datalist controls. I want to cache my pages but also I want to see the changes of data during the duration time of cache. I don't know how can I do that. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Quick tips: either use ajax + some web services (jquery, knockout & co are your friends) to separate the content of the page and the data, or use some [post cache substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx)

Comment: I used jquery with my web service and it solved. Thanks alot, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the pages but repopulate the datalists on each page refresh using [Post Cache Substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).